# Does MSGraph API possible connect to SharePoint on-premise?

Tags: development, microsoft-graph

Microsoft Graph API supports work with [Azure SharePoint sites](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/sharepoint). But is it possible to use it for SharePoint on-premise?

If so, how to pair them?

Comment: The similar question - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/218457/72824

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, it's possible to interact with resources from SharePoint online, but not from on-premise deployments. Microsoft Graph supports some on-prem scenarios, specifically, exposing [Exchange 2016 on-prem](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/deva/2017/07/22/use-microsoft-graph-api-to-reach-on-premises-cloud-users-of-hybrid-exchange-2016/) resources.

Comment: So answer is "No"! MsGraph doesn't able connect to SharePoint on-premises.

Comment: It's strange because SharePoint 2016 on-prem has hybrid mode too - 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-hybrid-4c89a95a-a58c-4fc1-974a-389d4f195383
Why only Exchange 2016 is supported by MSGraph?